# How do you update the firebase database when a user joins and leaves using discord.js + node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, discord.js

Once I've created X database using firebase how do you update the database when a user leaves (using discord.js + node.js). I have this already.

```
bot.on('guildCreate', async gData => {
  db.collection('guilds').doc(gData.id).set({
    'guildID': gData.id,
    'guildName': gData.name,
    'guildOwner': gData.owner.user.username,
    'guildOwnerID': gData.owner.id,
    'guildMemberCount': gData.memberCount,
    'prefix': '!'
  });
});
```

This creates my entries on my database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The events you need are [`guildMemberAdd`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildMemberAdd) and [`guildMemberRemove`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildMemberRemove), and you can use them like so:

```js
bot.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
  // database query
});

bot.on('guildMemberRemove', member => {
  // database query
});
```

[**Discord.js Docs**](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome)

Comment: I already know how to do that but I was asking how do I the whole firebase function database

Comment: May I ask why you're inserting dynamic data into the database? It can change quite often, so what you'd have could be inaccurate. You can retrieve a guild through the `Client.guilds` collection, and a member through `Guild.members` collection.

Comment: I see I will go ahead and see what I can do because later on, I would like to connect the database to a webpage where the guilds owners/mods/users can view total members, etc.

Comment: You could establish a websocket and use the bot to check the given guild's info accurately through the Discord API instead of a database. For now, sorry I can't be of help with the database part.

Comment: Are you able to elaborate on the WebSocket if you can, thank you